# Haskell math type system fun

Tags: math, haskell

I have the following Haskell code

```
import Data.Int
import System.Environment

type Coord = (Int16, Int16)

distributePointsOverCircle :: Int16 -> Int16 -> [Coord]
distributePointsOverCircle points radius =
  [ (xOf point, yOf point) | point <- [1..points] ]
  where
    xOf x = abstract cos x
    yOf x = abstract sin x

    abstract :: RealFrac a => ( a -> a ) -> Int16 -> Int16
    abstract f x   = (radius *) . truncate . f . fromIntegral $ (angleIncrement * x) * truncate (pi / 180)
    angleIncrement = div 360 points

main = do
  [a,b] <- getArgs
  print $ distributePointsOverCircle (read a) (read b)
```

No matter what I pass to distributePointsOverCircle, it consistently gives me a list of however many Coords as I give points where each Coord's first element is the radius and second element is zero.  Obviously this is not an even distribution of points.

What am I doing wrong here?  Is there some type-system trickery fudging my numbers?  The function I am trying to produce, written in an imperative pseudocode would be.

```
distributePointsOverCircle( numberOfPoints, radius )
  angleIncrement = 360 / numberOfPoints
  points         = []

  for i in 0 to (numberOfPoints -1)
    p = Point()
    p.x = (radius * cos((angleIncrement * i) * (PI / 180)))
    p.y = (radius * sin((angleIncrement * i) * (PI / 180)))

    points[i] = p

  return points
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
import Data.Int
import System.Environment

type Coord = (Int16, Int16)

distributePointsOverCircle :: Int16 -> Int16 -> [Coord]
distributePointsOverCircle points radius =
  [ (xOf point, yOf point) | point <- [1..points] ]
  where
    xOf x = abstract cos x
    yOf x = abstract sin x
    iRadius = fromIntegral radius
    angleIncrement = div 360 points
    abstract f x = round . (iRadius *) . f $ angle * (pi / 180)
      where 
        angle = fromIntegral $ angleIncrement * x

main = do
  [a,b] <- getArgs
  print $ distributePointsOverCircle (read a) (read b)
```

As already mentioned, the problem was that you used truncate before multiplying so that among other things `truncate (pi / 180) == 0`. I also think you had some errors in your main function.

Comment: +1 for clear coding style.  I had a typo in main from transferring it by hand from my example on an internet-less comp.

Answer (score 5):

It gives you a list of (*r*, 0) because `truncate (pi / 180) == 0`. Remove the `truncate` and the code should work fine.

```
abstract f x = (radius *) . truncate . f $ fromIntegral (angleIncrement * x) * (pi / 180)
```

Comment: well, remove the truncate and get a type error :-) you also need to stick a `fromIntegral` in angleIncrement.

Comment: Also note that `div 360 points` is integer division and always zero for > 360 points. You probably want `360 / fromIntegral points`.